# Overriding get_urls() for a Django CMS plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm working with a custom plugin using Django-CMS 3.0.13:

```
class PromoPlugin(CMSPluginBase):

    . . .

    def get_urls(self):
        print 'here'  # <-- NEVER CALLED
        return super(CMSPluginBase, self).get_urls()
```

and trying to override `get_urls()` but my override is **never called**. `CMSPluginBase` inherits from `ModelAdmin` [(reference)](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/plugin_base.py#L95)... what am I overlooking?

### Edit

So, after some research, the *actual* problem that's happening is that the PlaceholderAdminMixin's [edit_plugin](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/admin/placeholderadmin.py#L127) url is stepping on another mixin's patterns, specifically those of [django-genericadmin](https://github.com/jschrewe/django-genericadmin).

I added a url pattern exactly matching the pattern that was being stepped on to my `PromoPlugin` class, but the pattern is probably registered too late to override the `edit_plugin` pattern. So, it looks like I'll be tweaking django-genericadmin's URLs.

I'm marking this answer as accepted since it's the correct way to augment a Plugin's URL patterns.

Comment: I see a ticket for this https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1058  but no idea if it fixed, ticket is very old ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMSPluginBase` subclasses `ModelAdmin`, but is hooked into `cms.plugin_pool.PluginPool`, not an admin site. Therefore not all APIs in `ModelAdmin` are used.

However since 3.0 can use [`get_plugin_urls`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/api_references.html#cms.plugin_base.CMSPluginBase.get_plugin_urls) API.